# Am I (reviewer) correct or is the researcher correct re: Bonferroni?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, manova, bonferroni

I've been asked to review an article for a low-tier journal, such that I am the only reviewer with stats knowledge (such as it is; I used to teach stats and advanced stats, but it's been a few years now).

Researcher has done a 4x2x2 Factorial ANOVA with 7 DVs.  My critique was that if they felt the 7 DVs were related, they ought to instead do a MANOVA to reduce FWE.  Failing that, they were at least obligated to do a correction on their p-values to acknowledge that they had done 7 ANOVAs.

Researcher returned a revised m.s. in which some of the p-values had changed and others hadn't, but they all remained significant.  Some of the original p-values had been listed as "less than" so I didn't have exact ps to work with (in other cases, whimsically, exact ps had been listed).

My understanding is that in doing Bonferroni, they had two choices:

1. divide the initial p-value (say, 0.05) by the number of comparisons to create a new standard of comparison (0.05 / 7 = 0.007).  By this standard, the numbers in their revised m.s. are incorrect and they are pushing insignificant p-values as though they're significant.
2. multiply the obtained p-value by the number of comparisons and see if they are still lower than  0.05.  By this standard, the numbers in their revised m.s. are still incorrect and they're still listing everything as significant.

In any case, I don't know why they didn't just do the MANOVA.

Their rebuttal to me was,

"It's clear the reviewer is using the number of dependent variables (7) when he should be using the number of comparisons (k) to calculate the confidence level correction.  As per Dunn, the scientist who pioneered using the Bonferroni method to study relationship between variables,  "Each of these methods may be extended to give confidence intervals for all possible linear combinations of the k means, as opposed to linear contrasts only." Further, Armstrong stated "By contrast, family-wise error correction occurs when a smaller number of related group means are compared often after a post-hoc procedure following analysis of variance (ANOVA)(also known as the Bonferroni post-hoc test)."

I think they're talking about mulitiple comparisons within one ANOVA (e.g., in their 4x2x2, whether or not they're interested in all 6 possible comparisons in the IV with 4 levels), although they haven't stated clearly that they weren't interested in examining some of these comparisons if this is the case.  But also, this doesn't deal with the fact that they ran 7 ANOVAs in the first place.  Unless they're treating significant individual Fs as "protective" and only doing corrections on the multiple comparisons *within* ANOVAs, which I believe to be a pretty liberal interpretation.

They've fought so much that I'm losing confidence in my understanding of this issue.  I would appreciate any clarity on the matter, and an explanation of how I might be correct or incorrect in the way I'm reviewing these results!

Comment: In (1), we don't divide the p-value by the # comparisons, we divide 1 - confidence level a.k.a. alpha.

Comment: Obviously, I have not read the paper, but MANOVA answers a different research question than multiple ANOVAs. In MANOVA, we ask if a set of common factors drive variation in a collection of DVs. We can get a p-value for this BIG hypotheses test, but it might not be of scientific interest to the researcher, and MANOVA tests aren't very actionable (my opinion). Multiple ANOVAs are useful if we want to understand the extent to which each factor drives variation in the individual responses. This is a more common scientific question.

Comment: You're right that they should not be ignoring that across ANOVA component. They're right that the most stringent (and possibility default) would be to divide by the number of tests considered (k), which accounts for both within and across ANOVAs. From their response, you guys seem to be on the same page, no?

Comment: @JTH: I believe their DVs are sufficiently correlated that MANOVA might be proscribed.  But even if mulitple ANOVAs is the answer, are they not beholden to adjust resulting ps for the fact that they've done 7 ANOVAs?

Comment: @user257566: with a 4x2x2 ANOVA run on 7 DVs, a I correct then that the number of tests considered is likely to be even higher than 7, not lower?  I.e., this would not make their data any more likely to show significance.

Comment: Also, @JTH: if I understand correctly, 1-(1-alpha)^k tells us the probability of finding a false positive.  The correction itself is simply alpha/k.  See, e.g.,:https://toptipbio.com/bonferroni-correction-method/

Comment: @JasperRabbit It depends on the test they're doing, but if it's more than one per ANOVA, than the total number of tests is more than 7